# Rails - paperclip not uploading photos? shows missing.png

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I installed Paperclip gem, used it to generate :image column in my model. Then edited view to let me upload photo:

```
<%= form_for @book = Book.new, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
...
...
...

<%= f.file_field :image %>
```

In my model I entered this line:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :smal => "200x200>"}
                  :url  => "/assets/books/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/books/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

I can choose to upload photo, when I upload it, it gives error as missing.png, even though image name was not like that, it seems that photo was not uploaded at all. What could be wrong?
EDIT: full error:

```
    No route matches [GET] "/assets/books/17/small/thunderbird-logo-200x200.png"

 actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (5.9ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (27.2ms)
```

Comment: can you paste the actual image.  Uploading wouldnt give you that message.  Missing.png is the image name is uses by default when an image doesnt exist for a model that uses paperclip.  Sounds like you have some other validation failure or your output code isnt correct

Comment: It seems it's uploading images, but when it needs to show it, it can't find where it uploaded.. It uploads to /public/system/books/images/000/000/013/small. How can I tell system to know where it uploaded that image?..

Comment: It gives this error:
`No route matches [GET] "/system/books/images/000/000/013/small/thunderbird-logo-200x200.png"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the path and url

```
    has_attached_file :image,
      :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
      :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", 
      :styles => { :smal => "200x200>" }
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with routing. As even if I set whole path, it still throws route error.

Comment: Can you update your question with the path & url that you're setting?

Comment: Updated question. The thing is if I change path, it still correctly upload photos there, but I can't see it through browser...

Comment: and how are you calling the image to display it in your view?

Comment: `<%= image_tag @book.image.url(:small) %>`

Comment: Your style is using :smal not :small, is that a typo in stack overflow or does your model really say that?

Comment: Yes! that was the problem.. Thanks. I noticed that when deleted :small from template, then large photo appeared.

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is an extra set of eyes :)

Comment: Yeah. sometimes it so hard to notice such simple problem..:)

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this mistake by adding in you controller private service_params

Contoller:

```
  private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_service
  @service = Service.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def service_params
  params.require(:service).permit(:title, :about, :price, :photo)
end
```

You must add :photo to :title, :about, :price (or something lee what you have)

Comment: Very common mistake after adding new fields to add params into controller too. Thanks!